# How to remove a specific node using VTD-XML parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, vtd-xml

With the VTD-XML parser how do I do below.

```
<root>
     <A>
      <B>
        <c>1<c/>
        <d>2<d/>
        <e>3<e/>
      </B>
      <B>
        <c>1<c/>
        <d>2<d/>
        <e>3<e/>
      </B>
     </A>
 </root>
```

In the above xml how do I remove only nodes has tag name `<B>` ?

So my final out put should be

```
<root>
     <A>
     </A>
</root>
```

Comment: @Rahul sorry for misleading. I need to know how to do this in VTD-XML parser

Comment: do you need code examples or just instructions so you can go ahead try to come with your own code?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author it would be grateful if you can provide the samples so everybody can understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that removes all child nodes of A, the key is VTDNav's getContentFragment().

```
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class removeNode {

    public  static void main(String s[]) throws Exception{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        boolean b = vg.parseFile("input.xml", false);
        if (b==false)
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        vn.toElement(VTDNav.FC); // get to A node
        long l = vn.getContentFragment();
        xm.remove(l);
        xm.output("output.xml");
    }
}
```